# Iphone 6plus safari landscape links not working

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, landscape

Has anyone else had the problem of links at the top of a website not being clickable until you scroll down and hide the URL bar? It only seems to happen in Safari iPhone 6 plus landscape view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! And it it happens on ALL iPhone 6 plus phones. I've experimented with several. I've  discovered that the problem is isolated to Safari, so a 3rd party browser will eliminate the problem completely.